# Decompose real positive-definite symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Can any $M\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}_{\text{sym}+}$ (real, positive-definite, symmetric matrix) be decomposed in $M=C^{T}.C$ with $C\in \text{GL}_n(R)$ and vice versa ($C\in \text{GL}_n(R)\implies C^{T}.C\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}_{\text{sym}+}$)?

This question is related to inner products on real n-dim vector spaces with associated matrices $M\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}_{\text{sym}+}$. Under a basis transformation with associated matrix $C\in \text{GL}_n(R)$, the Gram matrix $M$ transforms as follows
$$M_b=C^T\cdot M_e\cdot C$$
If we choose $M_e=\text{id}$ then all other possible Gram matrices $M_b$ can be constructed by changing the basis so that $M_b=C^T\cdot C$ (at least if the statement in the beginning is true). If this is true, is their a way to characterize a real inner product on the basis of its Gram matrix? Maybe the basis choice for which $M_e=\text{id}$? And if so, when is this choice Euclidean?

Comment: You can use [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

Comment: Yes, but is the triangular matrix in Cholesky decomposition necessarily invertible?

Comment: Is the product of two noninvertible matrices invertible?

Comment: What do you mean by "Euclidean"? Why not use the Spectral Theorem to get, in fact, a unique positive symmetric square root? You should be able to check directly that for any $C\in GL_n(\mathbb R)$, the matrix $C^\top C$ is symmetric; positive definiteness is most easily decided by considering $C^\top Cx\cdot x$ for any $x\ne 0$.

Comment: I see, so I can decompose $M$ as stated. The reason why I wanted to check is because of the mess it gets me in to in terms of inner products. They are not determined by their Gram matrix (since any $M$ can be reached by transforming the basis), but maybe by the choice of basis for which the Gram matrix is the identity?

Comment: If you endow a real (finite dimensional) vector space with a particular inner product (the dot product) you get a Euclidean vector space. So with "the Euclidean choice" I mean, the inner product in Euclidean vector spaces, as opposed to any other inner product on real vector spaces.

Comment: @TedShifrin: since your comment answers the question, I suggest you make it into an answer proper.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, I guess I will have to. In general, I prefer to try to coax the OP to follow my hints/suggestions and write his/her own solution.

Comment: @Ted: I wholeheartedly agree, but reality is that it almost never happens, and hundreds of questions appear as unanswered when in fact an answer is in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're thinking of $M$ as the Gram matrix for a particular basis (which is just the matrix for the inner product as a symmetric bilinear form). There is an orthonormal basis on $\mathbb R^n$ with respect to this inner product, and so, yes, you can change basis to make $M$ turn into the identity matrix. (BTW, this works with any nondegenerate symmetric form, not necessarily positive-definite.)

But, to answer your more general question, for any $C\in GL_n(\mathbb R)$, the matrix $C^\top C$ is symmetric (just take its transpose) and positive-definite ($C^\top Cx\cdot x = Cx\cdot Cx  = \|Cx\|^2\ne 0$, since $C$ is nonsingular). Conversely, by the Spectral Theorem, there is an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of your given $M$. Moreover, since $M$ is positive definite, every eigenvalue is positive (see the calculation just above), and so $M=Q \Lambda Q^\top$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q$ and some diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ with positive entries. Now take $C=Q\sqrt\Lambda Q^\top$, where $\sqrt\Lambda$ denotes the diagonal matrix whose entries are the (positive) square roots of the entries of $\Lambda$. $C$ is a symmetric matrix with $C^2 = M$.